# For loop not iterating through the whole loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

In Excel VBA I have 2 loops - the i loop and the j loop. When the program runs into the j loop, the loop is supposed to run 9 times since i=9. But the j loop runs only once.

```
Public Sub ArrayReader(ByRef internalArray() As String, ByRef s As String)

Dim j As Integer
Dim str1 As String

For i = LBound(internalArray) To UBound(internalArray)
  If internalArray(i) = "(" Then
   MsgBox "check" & i
    For j = 0 To j = i
     str1 = str1 & internalArray(j)
     MsgBox "j loop is running. Iteration#:" & j
    Next j
   MsgBox str1 & "J value is:" & j
   MsgBox "I value is:" & i
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: your amazing - that worked pls post answer below and i will vote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close.  You just need to change your loop statement to `For j = 0 To i` instead of `For j = 0 To j = i`.